# How can i make a youtube downloader and compilation maker

Tags: java, python, web-scraping, software-design

I want to build a youtube downloader that can download the top videos of a given category (like dogs, birds, etc)  and compile the downloaded videos.
What libraries or GitHub repos should I use? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For web-scraping you will need at least: [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/), [Requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests2/) and something like [pytube](https://pypi.org/project/pytube/). Can't say about compiling videos, because I didn't do that. But those three will give you a good start.